# Inconsisten Jquerymobile body/height rendering on android mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm trying to make a jquerymobile site with header and footer to render consistently across mobile environments, but for some reason when I test it on an android web device the body extends way out of whack after orientation change and doesn't render the same afterward.

Any ideas what might be causing it or how to fix it?
I've tried hiding the overflow, and even playing with the height/width for page data role, but nothing seems to be working.  This issue isn't appearing on any of iOS devices just my Android ones.

A working example can be found [here](http://locus.is/testExample/index3.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=YES">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var appleHeightOffset = 60;
var orientation = window.orientation;
var oMod = (parseInt(orientation)/90);

function isMobileSafari() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone)/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/);
}

$(document).on('pageinit',function() {
    if ( oMod == 1 || oMod == -1 ){
        renderLandscape($(window).height(),$(window).width());
    }else if( oMod == 0 || oMod == 2 ){
        renderPortrait($(window).height(),$(window).width());
    }

});

    function renderPortrait(height,width){
        $(".ui-page").height(height + "px");
        $(".ui-page").width(width + "px");
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $("body").css("background-color", "Red");
        $("#mainpage").css("background-color", "Aquamarine");
        $("#mainHeader").css("background-color", "Brown");
        $("#mainContent").css("background-color", "DarkGreen");
        $("#mainFooter").css("background-color", "Gold");       

        $("#mainFooter, #mainHeader, #mainContent").width(width + "px");   
        $("#mainHeader").height( (width / 9) + "px");
        $("#mainFooter").height( (width / 6) + "px");

        var contentHeight = height - ($("#mainHeader").height() + $("#mainFooter").height());   
        if (isMobileSafari()) { 
            contentHeight += appleHeightOffset;
        }
        $("#mainContent").height(contentHeight);
    }


    function renderLandscape(height,width){
        $(".ui-page").height(height + "px");
        $(".ui-page").width(width + "px");
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $("body").css("background-color", "Red");
        $("#mainpage").css("background-color", "Aquamarine");
        $("#mainHeader").css("background-color", "Brown");
        $("#mainContent").css("background-color", "DarkGreen");
        $("#mainFooter").css("background-color", "Gold");       

        $("#mainFooter, #mainHeader, #mainContent").width(width + "px");
        $("#mainHeader").height( (height / 6) + "px");
        $("#mainFooter").height( (height / 4) + "px");

        var contentHeight = height - ($("#mainHeader").height() + $("#mainFooter").height());   
        if (isMobileSafari()) { 
            contentHeight += appleHeightOffset;
        }
        $("#mainContent").height(contentHeight);
    }

    function hideAddressBar(){
        if(!window.location.hash){
            if(document.height < window.outerHeight){
                document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
            }
            setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 50 );
        }
    }

    $(window).bind('orientationchange', function(e){
        hideAddressBar();
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.scrollTo(0,1);
            var oMod = (parseInt(window.orientation)/90);
            var height = $(window).height();
            var width = $(window).width();      

            if ( oMod == 1 || oMod == -1 ){
                renderLandscape(height,width);
            }else if( oMod == 0 || oMod == 2 ){
                renderPortrait(height,width);
            }
        },500);
    });

    function findNearest() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionNearest, positionError);
        } else {
            positionError(-1);
        }
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
    <div data-role="header" id="mainHeader">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="mainContent">
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" id="mainFooter">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery Mobile is cross-platform and responsive without any further modifications, however, it does partially support old platforms. check this http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Comment: Thats the problem, I'm using jquerymobile, that's why I'm so confused by how things are so inconsistently being rendered.

Comment: what are you exactly facing _without the modification above_?

Comment: Near as I can tell, something is causing the body area itself to become considerably larger than the screen, even though nothing is being done modify the dimensions of the body itself. I would put the script up on something like jsfiddle but I can't seem to find anything that handles Jquery Mobile

Comment: Or rather I can't even get jsfiddle to run it correctly

Comment: it happens when showing a map?

Comment: Sorry, that line should have been taken out. There was a map but I removed it to test to see if it was the culprit. Even without that line I'm still seeing the problems I mentioned.

Comment: are you adding a div with `data-role="content"`?

Comment: Just tried that, edited the example code to match. No luck.  There is a working example here: http://locus.is/testExample/index3.html

Comment: I also tried earlier simply removing the data roles for the divs, but still the same issue occurred.

Comment: add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` to `head`

Comment: Problem still persists, and now the content div stretches further than the width of the screen.

Comment: The new width issue is resolved if I remove the lines to changed the width of the headear, content, and footer divs `$("#mainFooter, #mainHeader, #mainContent").width(width + "px");` from both functions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31346/discussion-between-omar-and-vikinggoat)